# Media query fails at 1023px width for Windows

Tags: html, angular, sass, media-queries

I am trying to set media queries so that a webpage is responsive and switches the view if width is less than 1024px. But when the width in Google chrome DevTools is set to 1023px the media query is not applied. See the following class as an example:

```
.test {
  @media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
    border: 2px solid green;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 1023px) {
    border: 2px solid red;
  }
}
```

I want to set border to red if width is 1023 or less and to green if width is greater or equal to 1024. But at exactly 1023 no border is seen. It works fine for other widths.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wzw4fp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html
2. In Stackblitz, click on Open in New Window (right side top corner), then press F12
3. Click on Toggle device toolbar
4. Set width to 1023

Actual: Border is not seen at 1023px width

Expected: Red border is seen at 1023px width

The issue is there on Windows 10 on all browsers: Firefox, Google chrome, IE etc.
I am writing an Angular application but I expect this is nothing to with angular.

Any idea if this is a bug or what is wrong?

P.S: Not reproducible on Linux and MacOS! It works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Unable to reproduce on two of my Windows 10 machines (one being a high ppi display).

However, it is more ideal to use `em` when defining media queries in CSS. This is because a pixel may not equal a pixel on all devices. This is increasingly true when people may change the default UI/text size in their browser or OS.

Lastly, rather than declaring styles for each screen range try to declare your mobile (smallest screen) styles as default, then add modifying styles as your screen grows wider.

Try the following and see if you still experience the issue:

```
.test {
  border: 2px solid red;
  @media screen and (min-width: 64em) {
    border: 2px solid green;
  }
}
```

EDIT: Added screenshot for confirmation

[image]

Comment: thanks for the reply. I actually need use several breakpoints for various device widths like mobile, tablet, desktop. So I need styles for various screen ranges. A similar problem also exists at 1279px if max-width is set to 1280px. To reproduce you could try any Angular application, just use a div with some text in it add scss class .test. At 1022px you should see red border, At 1023px no border, at 1024px you should see green border. The no media query works at 1023px.

Comment: Also I tried changing the unit to em, but same problem occurs

Comment: You can use my example and add more `min-width` declarations as your screen gets wider. Just saying you don't have to explicitly set the `0 ~ 1st Breakpoint` media query. Lastly, I used your StackBlitz in attempts to reproduce the issue. That is indeed odd.

Comment: Confirming on Win10... 1023 is fine.

Answer (score 0):

This inconsistency could be due to various factors, including browser zoom settings, device pixel density, or browser rendering quirks.

Press the Windows logo key+U or select Start > Settings > Accessibility. Select Text size.

**Change the size of apps and text on main display** to 100% and **option of Drag the slider the sample text is to render then click apply** to 100%, Issue will resolve